# Compiling sparse 0.4.1

Tags: c, gcc

I'm trying to compile a project that relies on sparse 0.4.1, but in trying to compile sparse 0.4.1 I end up with the following compiler error:

```
included from parse.c:25:
./parse.h:63:22: error: member of anonymous struct redeclares 'label_statement'
                        struct statement *label_statement;
                                          ^
./parse.h:40:22: note: previous declaration is here
                        struct statement *label_statement;
```

This is confusing to me, since they are different members of two different structs, so why is it complaining?

The code looks like this:

```
struct statement {
    enum statement_type type;
    struct position pos;
    union {
            struct /* declaration */ {
                    struct symbol_list *declaration;
            };
            struct /* label_arg */ {
                    struct symbol *label;
                    struct statement *label_statement;
            };
            struct {
                    struct expression *expression;
                    struct expression *context;
            };
            struct /* return_statement */ {
                    struct expression *ret_value;
                    struct symbol *ret_target;
            };
            struct /* if_statement */ {
                    struct expression *if_conditional;
                    struct statement *if_true;
                    struct statement *if_false;
            };
            struct /* compound_struct */ {
                    struct statement_list *stmts;
                    struct symbol *ret;
                    struct symbol *inline_fn;
                    struct statement *args;
            };
            struct /* labeled_struct */ {
                    struct symbol *label_identifier;
                    struct statement *label_statement;
            };
.......
```

Comment: What compiler? Output looks a bit like GCC, but AFAIK new GCCs accept anonymous union members. What version of the compiler are you using and what compiler and what `CFLAGS`?

Answer (score 2):

you declare the statement label_statement two times in the same union , the first in the line 40 and the seconde in the line 63

```
     struct statement *label_statement;
```

try to edit the name of the second one.